# Resources for step-by-step SEO case studies?

Tags: seo

I'm currently reading *The Art of SEO* and I'm finding that it is mostly theory (600 pages of it). Theory is nice, but I would also like to complement the theory with some concrete, step-by-step case studies done by experts in the SEO field. So for example, similar to what Eric Ries accomplished in *The Lean Startup*. I am not looking for short portfolio piece descriptions by SEO practitioners; ideal candidate resources ought to be substantial and genuine SEO learning aids.

Has anyone come across such a resource that fits this description?

Comment: I found it is incomplete too. A 700+ pages book should really have a case study section.

Comment: A quick Google of "In depth SEO case studies" provides plenty of good articles that you can learn from. I doubt you'll ever find ones that are literally step by step, seeing as many strategies would include hundreds (if not thousands) of steps.

Comment: Although this is not a direct answer, I would be very careful with case studies - SEO 'rules' change so often that a case study may not always be helpful since what once worked, no longer does, and what things no longer work are now working (META tags for example worked, didn't work, and are now holding weight again). Not only that, but the exact same methods applied to one site may not work on the other. There is no quick way to learn SEO (IMO), it is truely about testing the water yourself. Do it slowly so you can view the results and always make sure you know what you're measuring (EG, key

Comment: Why don't you Google "SEO case studies"? Search results seem good, thought not precise and professional!